# Import and edit excel file in browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to improt an excel file from desktop in the browser and then want to edit that excel in the browser and then save.

Also by clicking on export save that file on desktop.

Here i want to use spring, hibernate and mysql DB.

Please suggest any code example or the best way that i have need to use.

Note:- i have googled it so many times but nothing found suitable.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: How much you can spend to get this done? Because I don't think you will get your project done for free by anyone on SO

Comment: [OpenXLS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openxls/) is as close to your requirements as it gets.

Comment: http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Sounds like a job for Google Docs